# How To pass data from angularjs to javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to pass data from angularjs to javascript

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="data.value" id="MyData">

<script>

  var MyData = GetEelementById(MyData).value;

</script>
```

i cant make it work .. , what is the correct way ?

Comment: You are using wrong syntax. It will be `document.getElementById('MyData')`

Comment: I think you're missing one of the main points of using angularjs, the fact that the values are already bound in JavaScript.

Comment: Can I (respectfully) suggest you go and run through some basic angular tutorials - this is the most basic stuff to understand in angular.

Comment: document.getElementById('MyData') i use this already it still not working

Answer (score 1):

The above piece of code is just part of VIEW only.

You need to go through basic tutorials of AngularJs and understand how views and controllers work.

To be specific, You can access the data (you expecting) in the controller of the view.

Like:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input ng-model="data.value" id="MyData">
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data={
     value:"Deepak"
    }
});
</script>
```

#### Edit as per the discussion in comments on answer

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.data={
         value:"Deepak"
        }
// $scope.data.value is the initial value for the model and view is rendered with this value intially.
   //You can also change this value with javascript to reflect in the view as well
    //Your post request comes here
    // **$scope.data.value reflects the updated Value of Input Box**
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: actually... i use an http request from angularjs      $http.post("../../App/Api/Api_Member/Api_Member_Business/Member_ViewBusinessList.php")
.then(function(data){

$scope.DisplayBusiness = data.data;

console.log("Display Business :", data);

});           and i want some of the data to pass in the javascript

Comment: Yeah, If I'm getting this right,  you want to access the input box value in javascript  and send it in the request?

Comment: i want to pass the value from angular to html... then access the data with javascript ... , there's a reason why i need to do it....

Comment: Okay cool, then you can to the post request inside the controller code. Also, as you type in the inputbox, the value gets reflected in the **$scope.data.value** 
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data={
     value:"Deepak"
    }

//Your post request comes here with. $scope.data.value is update with input box value
});

Comment: <input type="hidden" ng-model="Data.MyValue" id="GetThisValue">   , let say i have a value in my http request ... so i will be placing it like that ? .. , and fetch with  var GetValue = GetEelementById('GetThisValue').value;

Comment: If you want to update the input value from request, then you need to do :
**$scope.data.value='Some new value';**

And **you do not need GetElementById for Getting value**, You simply have the **value as $scope.data.value** if you write inside the controller function

See the edited part of answer